# Landscape weightmap texture values in UE5 (C++)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

In my character inherited cpp class I have a raycast function where I want to get the blend weight values of the Landscape material layers. For example, if the main character stands on the Landscape and the Landscape below has 2 textures painted upon it with different percentage (say, one texture is 40%, another is 60%), so I want to know these values. I was able to do that in Unity in C# quite easily but I'm struggling to do that in UE5 for 2 weeks already.

Was trying to find these values in the the material scripts but failed. Only some hints. In "MaterialShared.h" there's a function: "`const TArray<FStaticTerrainLayerWeightParameter> &GetTerrainLayerWeightParameters() const  { return TerrainLayerWeightParameters; }`" but I'm not sure if this is it, also I don't know how to get this function in my script. Any suggestions will be appreciated!